# ui.bootstrap.modal: Possible to get an event on esc and backdrop click

Tags: angular-ui

Is there a possibility to get an event when a modal closes on an Esc or backdrop click? Or is is possible to get a model change when the modal closes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to bootstrap docs you can only use following events: 'show', 'shown', 'hide', 'hidden'
Though if you want to detect if it was closed on pressing Esc key, or clicking backdrop you can bind your own event handlers

e.g. with jquery

```
$('.modal-backdrop').click(function(){
    //backdrop clicked
})

$(document).keyup(function(e){
if(e.which == 27&&$('body').hasClass('modal-open')){
 // esc pressed while modal is opened
}
})
```

Comment: This code does detect keyup/keydown on the esc key, however regardless of whether you use 'keyup' or 'keydown', the event occurs AFTER the modal has been hidden.

So you can't use it to PREVENT the esc closing the modal, but at least you can be aware that it has happened